# No current at light switch

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am trying to troubleshoot two light switches near each other that are not working. None of the wires to the switches have power. None of the circuit breakers are tripped so I am not sure where to go next.

These switches are not near any GFCI outlets, but before I go crazy looking for one that doesn't exist, is there anything I can do at the switch to determine if it is on a GFCI circuit that has tripped? I saw somewhere that if there is no continuity between ground and neutral that means a tripped GFCI, is there any truth to that, should I test for it?

Anything else I can do to troubleshoot further?

Thank you!

-more details-

A few more notes as I was able to tinker with this some more over the weekend.
One - this line has no GFCI outlets, so GFCI is not breaking the circuit. Two, I don't understand how these switches are wired, maybe someone can opine. Also whatever I said before about the neutral wire is irrelevant because there are no neutrals connected to any of the three switches.

There are three switches altogether in two separate electrical boxes - one standalone, and two as a pair. Neither of the two boxes housing these switches sets off a voltage detector pen. All three switches appear to be bog standard single pole switches.

1) Standalone switch has TWO BLACK wires coming into the single LINE connection and a SINGLE BLACK wire going out the LOAD connection. There are two ground wires attached to this switch. It seems like there are three cables in this box. 2 photos below.

[image: SingleSwitch1]

[image: SingleSwitch2]

2) The box with two switches has switch one with BLACK wire going into LINE connection and RED wire going out of LOAD, then ground. The second switch on the right has TWO BLACK LINES tapping into LINE, one black line coming out of LOAD and then also ground wire.

[image: DoubleSwitch]

Starting with the single switch, is it typical to have so many cables going into a single switch box? Is this switch splitting the circuit? Are these switches of correct type (they all seem to be regular single pole switches). Any ideas of what to look for? thank you

Comment: group == ground ?  do these switches even have a neutral?  Showing pics might be useful.

Comment: Yes group was meant to say ground, sorry - corrected. These switches have 3 wires - hot, neutral and green ground. Hot and neutral are top and bottom connections on the right side of the switch and ground is top left  I'll post a picture when I can.

Comment: if a switch only has two wires besides ground then neither is neutral. You have a hot-in and a switched-hot-out.

Comment: I see thank you for clarifying, yes that does sound like my wiring. I'll post a picture tomorrow

Comment: @agentp I was wrong - seems like there are two black wires going into the LINE terminal. I am now even more confused. Please see the post edit, where I've also added photos.

Comment: Can you get us more photos of the switches in the second box?